# R and probability

Tags: probability

I am trying to work out how to write and get a probability for the following problem. 52 cards are placed in 4 piles by suit. At random one card is picked from each pile to form a 4 card formation and then the cards are placed back on their piles. What is the probability of at least one Ace?

I have done the following but I don't think this is correct?

```
prob.card<- function(Ncards=13,Ntrials=1000){
  Nsample <-4
  trials <- matrix(sample.int(Nsample,Ncards*Ntrials,replace=T),Nsample)
  invalidtrials <- apply(trials,2,function(x) length(unique(x))<length(x))
  cat("The probability is:",sum(invalidtrials)/Ntrials,"\n")

}
prob.card(,1000)
```

How do i write this in R so i can get a probability?

Comment: This is not the correct stack for code review or programming-specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

OK so just a couple of things with your code. I think you want to swap the `Nsample` and `Ncards` variables in the `sample.int` call; right now you are sampling from 1:4 and I think you intend on sampling from 1:13. Also, you are counting as invalid trials any sample with any repeating cards. If you make small modifications to those two lines, I get something like this:

```
> prob.card <- function(Ncards=13,Ntrials=1000) {
+   Nsample <- 4
+   trials <- matrix(sample.int(Ncards,Nsample*Ntrials,replace=T),Nsample)
+   
+   # Let the number 1 be an ace
+   trialsWithAces <- apply(trials,2,function(x) ifelse(1 %in% x, 1, 0))
+   cat("The probability is:",sum(trialsWithAces)/Ntrials,"\n")
+ 
+ }
> prob.card(,100000)
The probability is: 0.27244 
>
```

Since the true probability of getting at least one ace is $1-(\frac{12}{13})^{4} = 0.273975$, I would say that is pretty close.